# After Angular 8 upgrade the Angular scripts are inserted at the start of the HTML document

Tags: javascript, angular, upgrade

I upgraded from Angular 7.2 to Angular 8 and now all the Angular scripts are inserted at the very start of the HTML (before `!DOCTYPE`).

Is this a bug? Does anyone know what might be causing it?

```
<script src="runtime.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills.js" defer></script><script src="styles.js" defer></script><script src="scripts.js" defer></script><script src="vendor.js" defer></script><script src="main.js" defer></script><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base href="/my-app/" />
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2" />
    <script src="./ng-app-settings.js"></script>
</head>
<app>Loading...</app>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/abcdefg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try { Typekit.load(); } catch (e) { }</script>
</html>
```

My original HTML is pretty standard. The only oddities are an ng-app-settings.js script that loads some JSON for app config and the use of the TypeKit service for fonts. Neither of these caused a problem for Angular 7.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2" />
    <script src="./ng-app-settings.js"></script>
</head>
<app>Loading...</app>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/abcdefg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try { Typekit.load(); } catch (e) { }</script>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you followed all the steps in [the upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0) ?

Comment: Yes, I'm going from 7.2 to 8.0 and it doesn't mention anything about changes in the HTML.

Comment: That's definitely not right. `<!DOCTYPE html>` should be the first line of your HTML.

Comment: Hmm from what I can see, your HTML is invalid, you don't even have a `<body>` on either. Usually what happens in webpack it looks for that body

Comment: @penleychan can't believe I didn't spot that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding **body** tags to your HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2" />
    <script src="./ng-app-settings.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/abcdefg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">try { Typekit.load(); } catch (e) { }</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: If it fixes the problem then it is an answer. But I can change the wording

Comment: It fixed the problem :)

Comment: thanks alot, it really improves the quality of your answer.